# Speeding up/slowing down video ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to change video speed using ffmpeg framework. I used this command for that:

`ffmpeg -y -i /storage/extSdCard/Video/1.avi -filter_complex [0:v]fps=50.0, setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a] -map [v] -map [a] -preset ultrafast /storage/emulated/0/VID-20170716-VidRotate1.mp4`

How can I guess the duration of the resulting video after slowing down or speeding up video?

This is my whole log in console:

```
ffmpeg -y -i /storage/extSdCard/Video/1.avi -filter_complex [0:v]fps=50.0, setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a] -map [v] -map [a] -preset ultrafast /storage/emulated/0/VID-20170716-VidRotate1.mp4 
    07-16 15:07:15.112: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
    07-16 15:07:15.112:   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
    07-16 15:07:15.112:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
    07-16 15:07:15.122:   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
    07-16 15:07:15.122:   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
    07-16 15:07:15.122:   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
    07-16 15:07:15.132:   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
    07-16 15:07:15.132:   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
    07-16 15:07:15.132:   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
    07-16 15:07:15.132:   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
    07-16 15:07:15.142:   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
    07-16 15:07:15.232: Input #0, avi, from '/storage/extSdCard/Video/1.avi':
    07-16 15:07:15.232:   Metadata:
    07-16 15:07:15.232:     encoder         : Lavf52.104.0
    07-16 15:07:15.232:   Duration: 00:02:03.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 773 kb/s
    07-16 15:07:15.242:     Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (xvid / 0x64697678), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 632 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    07-16 15:07:15.242:     Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    07-16 15:07:15.262 750-781/? W/ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.release()
    07-16 15:07:15.282: [libx264 @ 0xb5428800] using SAR=1/1
    07-16 15:07:15.312: [libx264 @ 0xb5428800] using cpu capabilities: none!
    07-16 15:07:15.422: [libx264 @ 0xb5428800] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1
    07-16 15:07:15.422: [libx264 @ 0xb5428800] 264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
    07-16 15:07:15.462: Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/VID-20170716-VidRotate1.mp4':
    07-16 15:07:15.462:   Metadata:
    07-16 15:07:15.462:     encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    07-16 15:07:15.462:     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 50 fps, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    07-16 15:07:15.462:     Metadata:
    07-16 15:07:15.462:       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264
    07-16 15:07:15.462:     Side data:
    07-16 15:07:15.462:       unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
    07-16 15:07:15.472:     Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    07-16 15:07:15.472:     Metadata:
    07-16 15:07:15.472:       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 aac
    07-16 15:07:15.472: Stream mapping:
    07-16 15:07:15.472:   Stream #0:0 (mpeg4) -> fps
    07-16 15:07:15.472:   Stream #0:1 (mp3) -> atempo
    07-16 15:07:15.472:   setpts -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
    07-16 15:07:15.472:   atempo -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
    07-16 15:07:15.472: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    07-16 15:07:15.532: Past duration 0.999992 too large
    07-16 15:07:15.972: frame=   24 fps=0.0 q=15.0 size=      62kB time=00:00:00.39 bitrate=1296.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=19 speed=0.781x    
    07-16 15:07:16.483: frame=   45 fps= 44 q=15.0 size=      63kB time=00:00:00.83 bitrate= 617.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=40 speed=0.827x    
    07-16 15:07:16.983: frame=   72 fps= 48 q=20.0 size=     104kB time=00:00:01.36 bitrate= 621.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=67 speed=0.906x    
    07-16 15:07:17.484: frame=   99 fps= 49 q=17.0 size=     171kB time=00:00:01.90 bitrate= 734.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=94 speed=0.942x    
    07-16 15:07:18.004: frame=  125 fps= 49 q=22.0 size=     208kB time=00:00:02.41 bitrate= 704.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=120 speed=0.953x    
    07-16 15:07:18.515: frame=  152 fps= 50 q=18.0 size=     334kB time=00:00:02.97 bitrate= 919.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=147 speed=0.979x    
    07-16 15:07:19.015: frame=  181 fps= 51 q=18.0 size=     407kB time=00:00:03.55 bitrate= 938.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=176 speed=   1x    
    07-16 15:07:19.516: frame=  209 fps= 52 q=16.0 size=     465kB time=00:00:04.13 bitrate= 921.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=204 speed=1.02x    
    07-16 15:07:20.026: frame=  234 fps= 51 q=15.0 size=     483kB time=00:00:04.59 bitrate= 860.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=229 speed=1.01x    
    07-16 15:07:20.527: frame=  258 fps= 51 q=20.0 size=     606kB time=00:00:05.08 bitrate= 975.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=253 speed=1.01x    
    07-16 15:07:21.047: frame=  291 fps= 52 q=15.0 size=     606kB time=00:00:05.73 bitrate= 866.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=286 speed=1.03x    
    07-16 15:07:21.558: frame=  317 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=     716kB time=00:00:06.24 bitrate= 938.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=312 speed=1.03x    
    07-16 15:07:22.048: frame=  342 fps= 52 q=17.0 size=     781kB time=00:00:06.75 bitrate= 947.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=337 speed=1.03x    
    07-16 15:07:22.549: frame=  367 fps= 52 q=20.0 size=     823kB time=00:00:07.26 bitrate= 927.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=362 speed=1.03x    
    07-16 15:07:23.049: frame=  393 fps= 52 q=19.0 size=     903kB time=00:00:07.77 bitrate= 951.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=388 speed=1.03x    
    07-16 15:07:23.560: frame=  421 fps= 52 q=17.0 size=     992kB time=00:00:08.33 bitrate= 974.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=416 speed=1.03x    
    07-16 15:07:24.060: frame=  448 fps= 52 q=15.0 size=    1016kB time=00:00:08.87 bitrate= 938.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=443 speed=1.03x    
    07-16 15:07:24.551: frame=  474 fps= 52 q=15.0 size=    1029kB time=00:00:09.40 bitrate= 896.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=469 speed=1.04x    
    07-16 15:07:25.061: frame=  500 fps= 52 q=15.0 size=    1029kB time=00:00:09.91 bitrate= 850.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=495 speed=1.03x    
    07-16 15:07:25.562: frame=  528 fps= 52 q=15.0 size=    1110kB time=00:00:10.49 bitrate= 866.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=523 speed=1.04x    
    07-16 15:07:26.052: frame=  560 fps= 53 q=15.0 size=    1114kB time=00:00:11.12 bitrate= 820.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=555 speed=1.05x    
    07-16 15:07:26.563: frame=  591 fps= 53 q=15.0 size=    1117kB time=00:00:11.74 bitrate= 779.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=586 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:07:27.063: frame=  621 fps= 54 q=18.0 size=    1154kB time=00:00:12.35 bitrate= 765.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=616 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:27.574: frame=  648 fps= 54 q=20.0 size=    1200kB time=00:00:12.91 bitrate= 761.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=643 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:28.084: frame=  675 fps= 54 q=20.0 size=    1292kB time=00:00:13.42 bitrate= 788.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=670 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:07:28.585: frame=  701 fps= 53 q=16.0 size=    1346kB time=00:00:13.95 bitrate= 790.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=696 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:07:29.085: frame=  729 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    1380kB time=00:00:14.48 bitrate= 780.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=724 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:07:29.616: frame=  753 fps= 53 q=12.0 size=    1380kB time=00:00:15.00 bitrate= 753.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=748 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:07:30.116: frame=  780 fps= 53 q=15.0 size=    1459kB time=00:00:15.51 bitrate= 770.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=775 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:07:30.627: frame=  812 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    1464kB time=00:00:16.16 bitrate= 742.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=807 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:31.127: frame=  843 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    1465kB time=00:00:16.78 bitrate= 715.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=838 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:31.638: frame=  875 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    1469kB time=00:00:17.41 bitrate= 691.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=870 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:32.138: frame=  906 fps= 54 q=18.0 size=    1507kB time=00:00:18.04 bitrate= 684.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=901 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:32.649: frame=  932 fps= 54 q=21.0 size=    1555kB time=00:00:18.55 bitrate= 686.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=927 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:33.159: frame=  960 fps= 54 q=23.0 size=    1614kB time=00:00:19.13 bitrate= 691.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=955 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:33.670: frame=  988 fps= 54 q=20.0 size=    1737kB time=00:00:19.66 bitrate= 723.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=983 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:34.180: frame= 1014 fps= 54 q=16.0 size=    1876kB time=00:00:20.22 bitrate= 759.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=1009 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:34.671: frame= 1042 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    1897kB time=00:00:20.75 bitrate= 748.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=1037 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:35.181: frame= 1069 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    1911kB time=00:00:21.29 bitrate= 735.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=1064 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:35.692: frame= 1098 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    1912kB time=00:00:21.89 bitrate= 715.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=1093 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:36.182: frame= 1126 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    1918kB time=00:00:22.43 bitrate= 700.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=1121 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:36.703: frame= 1154 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    1918kB time=00:00:23.01 bitrate= 682.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=1149 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:37.203: frame= 1182 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    1952kB time=00:00:23.56 bitrate= 678.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=1177 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:37.724: frame= 1212 fps= 54 q=21.0 size=    1990kB time=00:00:24.19 bitrate= 673.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=1207 speed=1.09x    
    07-16 15:07:38.224: frame= 1240 fps= 55 q=20.0 size=    2085kB time=00:00:24.72 bitrate= 690.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=1235 speed=1.09x    
    07-16 15:07:38.725: frame= 1267 fps= 54 q=16.0 size=    2227kB time=00:00:25.28 bitrate= 721.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=1262 speed=1.09x    
    07-16 15:07:39.235: frame= 1296 fps= 55 q=15.0 size=    2266kB time=00:00:25.86 bitrate= 717.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=1291 speed=1.09x    
    07-16 15:07:39.736: frame= 1321 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    2279kB time=00:00:26.35 bitrate= 708.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=1316 speed=1.09x    
    07-16 15:07:40.236: frame= 1348 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    2279kB time=00:00:26.91 bitrate= 693.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=1343 speed=1.09x    
    07-16 15:07:40.747: frame= 1375 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    2288kB time=00:00:27.42 bitrate= 683.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=1370 speed=1.09x    
    07-16 15:07:41.237: frame= 1402 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    2289kB time=00:00:27.95 bitrate= 670.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=1397 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:41.768: frame= 1430 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    2294kB time=00:00:28.53 bitrate= 658.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=1425 speed=1.09x    
    07-16 15:07:42.278: frame= 1456 fps= 54 q=22.0 size=    2296kB time=00:00:29.04 bitrate= 647.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=1451 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:42.779: frame= 1485 fps= 54 q=21.0 size=    2350kB time=00:00:29.62 bitrate= 649.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=1480 speed=1.09x    
    07-16 15:07:43.279: frame= 1512 fps= 54 q=20.0 size=    2492kB time=00:00:30.16 bitrate= 676.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=1507 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:43.790: frame= 1539 fps= 54 q=16.0 size=    2562kB time=00:00:30.72 bitrate= 683.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=1534 speed=1.09x    
    07-16 15:07:44.290: frame= 1566 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    2581kB time=00:00:31.25 bitrate= 676.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=1561 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:44.801: frame= 1592 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    2581kB time=00:00:31.76 bitrate= 665.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=1587 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:45.301: frame= 1619 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    2589kB time=00:00:32.29 bitrate= 656.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=1614 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:45.802: frame= 1646 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    2589kB time=00:00:32.83 bitrate= 646.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=1641 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:46.332: frame= 1672 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    2593kB time=00:00:33.39 bitrate= 636.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=1667 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:46.823: frame= 1698 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    2594kB time=00:00:33.87 bitrate= 627.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=1693 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:47.333: frame= 1724 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    2597kB time=00:00:34.43 bitrate= 617.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=1719 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:47.844: frame= 1748 fps= 54 q=17.0 size=    2661kB time=00:00:34.89 bitrate= 624.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=1743 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:48.344: frame= 1775 fps= 54 q=22.0 size=    2731kB time=00:00:35.43 bitrate= 631.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=1770 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:48.865: frame= 1800 fps= 54 q=19.0 size=    2867kB time=00:00:35.92 bitrate= 653.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=1795 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:49.375: frame= 1826 fps= 54 q=17.0 size=    2968kB time=00:00:36.43 bitrate= 667.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=1821 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:49.876: frame= 1854 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    3014kB time=00:00:36.98 bitrate= 667.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=1849 speed=1.08x    
    07-16 15:07:50.366: frame= 1878 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    3041kB time=00:00:37.47 bitrate= 664.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=1873 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:50.877: frame= 1904 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    3052kB time=00:00:38.01 bitrate= 657.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=1899 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:51.387: frame= 1929 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    3056kB time=00:00:38.49 bitrate= 650.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=1924 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:51.888: frame= 1955 fps= 54 q=17.0 size=    3060kB time=00:00:39.03 bitrate= 642.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=1950 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:52.388: frame= 1981 fps= 54 q=17.0 size=    3062kB time=00:00:39.54 bitrate= 634.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=1976 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:52.899: frame= 2007 fps= 54 q=25.0 size=    3064kB time=00:00:40.07 bitrate= 626.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=2002 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:53.419: frame= 2036 fps= 54 q=20.0 size=    3255kB time=00:00:40.63 bitrate= 656.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=2031 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:53.920: frame= 2061 fps= 54 q=21.0 size=    3306kB time=00:00:41.14 bitrate= 658.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=2056 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:54.420: frame= 2089 fps= 54 q=17.0 size=    3371kB time=00:00:41.70 bitrate= 662.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=2084 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:54.910: frame= 2116 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    3438kB time=00:00:42.23 bitrate= 666.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=2111 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:55.421: frame= 2139 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    3460kB time=00:00:42.70 bitrate= 663.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=2134 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:55.921: frame= 2164 fps= 53 q=15.0 size=    3467kB time=00:00:43.21 bitrate= 657.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=2159 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:56.422: frame= 2189 fps= 53 q=15.0 size=    3470kB time=00:00:43.69 bitrate= 650.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=2184 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:56.932: frame= 2214 fps= 53 q=15.0 size=    3472kB time=00:00:44.21 bitrate= 643.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=2209 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:57.433: frame= 2235 fps= 53 q=15.0 size=    3474kB time=00:00:44.60 bitrate= 637.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=2230 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:07:57.943: frame= 2260 fps= 53 q=16.0 size=    3547kB time=00:00:45.13 bitrate= 643.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=2255 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:07:58.454: frame= 2292 fps= 53 q=24.0 size=    3555kB time=00:00:45.76 bitrate= 636.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=2287 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:07:58.964: frame= 2320 fps= 53 q=21.0 size=    3643kB time=00:00:46.34 bitrate= 643.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=2315 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:59.475: frame= 2348 fps= 53 q=16.0 size=    3700kB time=00:00:46.88 bitrate= 646.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=2343 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:07:59.985: frame= 2375 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    3755kB time=00:00:47.43 bitrate= 648.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=2370 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:00.486: frame= 2400 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    3880kB time=00:00:47.92 bitrate= 663.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=2395 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:08:00.996: frame= 2427 fps= 53 q=15.0 size=    3977kB time=00:00:48.46 bitrate= 672.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=2422 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:08:01.497: frame= 2456 fps= 53 q=18.0 size=    4012kB time=00:00:49.06 bitrate= 669.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=2451 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:01.997: frame= 2481 fps= 53 q=16.0 size=    4029kB time=00:00:49.55 bitrate= 666.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=2476 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:08:02.498: frame= 2507 fps= 53 q=20.0 size=    4036kB time=00:00:50.06 bitrate= 660.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=2502 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:08:03.008: frame= 2538 fps= 53 q=15.0 size=    4113kB time=00:00:50.68 bitrate= 664.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=2533 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:03.529: frame= 2568 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    4132kB time=00:00:51.26 bitrate= 660.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=2563 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:04.039: frame= 2596 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    4184kB time=00:00:51.85 bitrate= 661.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=2591 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:04.560: frame= 2623 fps= 53 q=23.0 size=    4276kB time=00:00:52.40 bitrate= 668.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=2618 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:05.060: frame= 2647 fps= 53 q=16.0 size=    4379kB time=00:00:52.87 bitrate= 678.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=2642 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:05.571: frame= 2671 fps= 53 q=19.0 size=    4425kB time=00:00:53.33 bitrate= 679.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=2666 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:08:06.071: frame= 2696 fps= 53 q=15.0 size=    4452kB time=00:00:53.87 bitrate= 677.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=2691 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:08:06.582: frame= 2723 fps= 53 q=15.0 size=    4478kB time=00:00:54.38 bitrate= 674.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=2718 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:08:07.102: frame= 2750 fps= 53 q=15.0 size=    4479kB time=00:00:54.91 bitrate= 668.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=2745 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:08:07.593: frame= 2779 fps= 53 q=15.0 size=    4558kB time=00:00:55.49 bitrate= 672.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=2774 speed=1.06x    
    07-16 15:08:08.093: frame= 2810 fps= 53 q=16.0 size=    4560kB time=00:00:56.12 bitrate= 665.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=2805 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:08.594: frame= 2841 fps= 53 q=21.0 size=    4565kB time=00:00:56.74 bitrate= 658.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=2836 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:09.104: frame= 2871 fps= 54 q=21.0 size=    4616kB time=00:00:57.33 bitrate= 659.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=2866 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:09.615: frame= 2897 fps= 54 q=22.0 size=    4673kB time=00:00:57.88 bitrate= 661.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=2892 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:10.115: frame= 2925 fps= 54 q=16.0 size=    4779kB time=00:00:58.42 bitrate= 670.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=2920 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:10.616: frame= 2951 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    4817kB time=00:00:58.95 bitrate= 669.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=2946 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:11.146: frame= 2978 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    4851kB time=00:00:59.51 bitrate= 667.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=2973 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:11.667: frame= 3007 fps= 54 q=21.0 size=    4852kB time=00:01:00.04 bitrate= 661.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=3002 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:12.157: frame= 3037 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    4933kB time=00:01:00.65 bitrate= 666.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=3032 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:12.648: frame= 3069 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    4939kB time=00:01:01.30 bitrate= 660.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=3064 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:13.148: frame= 3101 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=    4939kB time=00:01:01.88 bitrate= 653.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=3096 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:13.238: frame= 3101 fps= 54 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4994kB time=00:01:02.02 bitrate= 659.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=3096 speed=1.07x    
    07-16 15:08:13.238: video:4923kB audio:16kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.108781%
    07-16 15:08:13.248: [libx264 @ 0xb5428800] frame I:13    Avg QP:14.15  size: 72152
    07-16 15:08:13.248: [libx264 @ 0xb5428800] frame P:3088  Avg QP:17.25  size:  1329
    07-16 15:08:13.248: [libx264 @ 0xb5428800] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
    07-16 15:08:13.248: [libx264 @ 0xb5428800] mb P  I16..4:  0.8%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  7.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:92.2%
    07-16 15:08:13.248: [libx264 @ 0xb5428800] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 49.6% 59.6% 45.8% inter: 2.5% 4.8% 1.9%
    07-16 15:08:13.248: [libx264 @ 0xb5428800] i16 v,h,dc,p: 50% 26% 13% 10%
    07-16 15:08:13.248: [libx264 @ 0xb5428800] i8c dc,h,v,p: 45% 24% 21% 10%
    07-16 15:08:13.248: [libx264 @ 0xb5428800] kb/s:650.25
    07-16 15:08:13.258: [aac @ 0xb5429000] Qavg: 65536.000
```

Comment: Multiply the original duration by the same coefficient as used in the PTS filters.

Comment: @Mulvya Not that simple. I tried with video of 38 seconds duration. When I doubled speed of it "setpts="0.5*PTS", the resulting video is 7 seconds!!!!

Comment: Show the full console output.

Comment: @slhck OK, I deleted the question on Super User.

Comment: @slhck Either here or in Super User this is the command: ffmpeg -y -i /Videos/BJUhT_iBeSR.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a] -map [v] -map [a] -preset ultrafast /Videos/VID-20170716.mp4

Comment: Your input is 02:03.96 and your output is 01:02.02, so what is the problem, exactly?

Comment: @slhck The question is edited.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you change each timestamp (Presentation Timestamp, PTS) to be half of its original value, your video will be half as long.

So, if the PTS is `x * PTS`, then your final duration will be `x * duration`.

Example:

```
$ ffprobe -loglevel error input.mp4 -show_format -show_entries format=duration -of compact=p=0:nk=1
60.000000
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v 'setpts=0.5*PTS' -filter:a 'atempo=2' output.mp4
...
$ ffprobe -loglevel error output.mp4 -show_format -show_entries format=duration -of compact=p=0:nk=1
30.050000
```

Comment: Not that simple. I tried with video of 38 seconds duration. When I doubled speed of it "setpts="0.5*PTS", the resulting video is 7 seconds!!!! :)

Comment: There seems to be another factor affecting the duration of the resulting video.

Comment: You already said that, but then you need to show us the command line output from that 38 seconds file, not one that behaves predictably. (And ideally, upload the 38 seconds file somewhere.) You need to show an example that proves your problem, not one that works fine…

Comment: Have you tried before to speed up or slow down video using ffmpeg?

Comment: Yes, I have … why are you asking? Please supply a sample that shows the problem, and the respective command line output, otherwise I'm starting to think I'm just wasting my time here.

Comment: This the video link https://www.dropbox.com/s/sm3iaeugj3bsqo3/BWcZUSmhMYX.mp4?dl=0. Please prove your theory about calculating the duration of the resulting video and show us your command which you used to double the speed of the video. Then I will accept your answer.

Comment: It's maths, it's not a theory. If your last sample timestamp is, e.g., 38 seconds, and you multiply it by 0.5, it will be 19 seconds. Which is half the input duration. And when I take your video, which is 38.22 seconds long, and apply that filter, I get a 19.06 seconds long output. If that fails for you, please try again with a recent version of ffmpeg, in case that's a bug with the particular (older) version you're using.

Comment: It seems to be bug in ffmpeg which I use because I tried with another more recent version and the resulting video duration as expected 19 seconds, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I used this command to slow down video with half speed (e.g. more bass sound) audio

```
ffmpeg -i videoplayback.mp4  -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=2*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=0.5[a];[0:a]asetrate=44100*0.5,aresample=44100" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

I'm not a ffmpeg pro, but many commands out there resample the audio to get no pitch shift so it isn't a true slow down

Answer (score 1):

I faced that just recently.. Made a ffmpeg cli wrapper for my self.
src can be taken from: https://github.com/gadominas/autocut

Basically to slow/speedup video & audio you need to execute:

```
autocut -f tempo -i your_video_file.ext -t 120
```

also you can combine functions with autocut like:

```
autocut -f mkv2mp4,tempo,fade -i your_video_file.mkv -t 80 -h 20
```

that would convert your mkv to mp4, slow your video to 80% of original speed and apply fadein & fadeout for 20 frames from be begging & end.